# What does "hypostatize" mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology

What does the word "hypostatize" mean?

I have read various dictionary definitions, with examples, but I'm not sure I understand them.

For example, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypostatize):

> hypostatized; hypostatizing
>   transitive verb
>   : to attribute real identity to (a concept)
>
> Greek *hypostatos* substantially existing,

A comment below this question said it comes into English via "hypostatic".

Different people use hypostatic/hypostatis in different ways -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypostasis) for example suggests it has a perplexingly diverse set of meanings -- physical and metaphysical, and (within metaphysics) both real being and its opposite (illusion or fallacy) -- yet it sounds like a word that ought to mean something specific.

To help me understand how it comes to mean different things, could you perhaps explain how the meaning of the word relates to or derives from its etymology (its Greek roots)?

Comment: It is the American spelling of "hypostasize". You should find it in any reasonable dictionary.

Comment: Dictionaries state (assert) its meaning and etymology, but I don't understand (and would like you to explain) how its meaning relates to its etymology.

Comment: Are you asking to have its meaning explained or its origin? If it's meaning, what particular part of the definition is unclear?

Comment: I've read dictionary definitions of its meaning, but I don't (and would like to) understand how that meaning relates (or those meanings relate) to its etymology, how its meaning derives from or relates to its root words.

Comment: @ChrisW - are  the definitions given here  unclear?: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypostatize - : to attribute real identity to (a concept) from *Greek hypostatos substantially existing*.

Comment: There's e.g. discussion [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/English_as_a_lingua_NOT_so_franca-Whats_the_meaning_of_the_term_hypostatized) of what it means, and its etymology. The most plausible explanation there seems to me to be `meaning to personify, embody, or treat as real, from the Greek hypostatos :"placed under; "hypo-histasthai, "to place under"` except that I still don't see how its meaning (e.g. "treat as real") relates to its etymological roots (i.e. "[place](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%83%CF%84%CE%AC%CF%83%CE%B9%CF%82#Ancient_Greek) under").

Comment: @ChrisW -

***Origin of hypostatize***- 

1820–30; < Greek hypostat(ós) (see hypostatic) + -ize  - ***Origin of hypostatic*** - 1670–80; < Greek hypostatikós pertaining to substance, equivalent to hypostat(ós) ***placed under, giving support*** (hypo- hypo- + sta- stand + -tos verbal adjective suffix) + -ikos -ic - http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hypostatize

Comment: @user110518 That defines but doesn't explain the origin. I can read the dictionary definition[s] but I don't understand how the meaning[s] of the etymological root words may relate to, may imply, may become, the modern meaning of the modern word. Can you explain that, does it make sense to you?

Comment: @ChrisW - I think it is quite clear. The term hypostatic entered the English language first, and from that the verbal form hypostatize. The Greek root meaning pertaining  to substance, an extention of the original meaning of put under in the sense of giving support (to substance).

Comment: @user110518 So you're saying it derives from/via Christian doctrine on [the nature of the Trinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypostatic_union). OK if you say so, though I wouldn't call that "quite clear". But thank you: [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypostasis_(philosophy_and_religion)) didn't explain it to me, but [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypostatic_union#Hypostasis) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypostatic_union#cite_note-6) did.

Comment: @ChrisW Are you asking about the meaning of the Greek word υποστασις _hupostasis_ in the text Hebrews 1:3 : χαρακτὴρ τῆς ὑποστάσεως αὐτοῦ φέρων  ?

Comment: @NigelJ I get the impression from [this footnote #6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypostatic_union#cite_note-6) that the derivation from the roots is: "stand under", hence "substance" and "underlying", also "support", also "confidence" (as in, "a belief is substantiated or justified by some reason"). Hypostasis is there viewed as a good (desirable) thing in this context ... to that extent perhaps it's unlike a modern use of *[reification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(fallacy))* when that's viewed as a type of logical fallacy.

Comment: I think this question calls for a warning: a word’s current meaning has no obligation to relate to the roots it originated from. An oak looks nothing like an acorn, and neither can you substitute one for the other in any application of either. You should treat meaning and etymology as independent. A word means what people use it to mean. Most people don’t know or care where the word came from, and still use the word to mean what they intend it to mean. Insisting a word’s current meaning should clearly or causally relate to its origins is a quixotic quest, and will only end in heartbreak.

Comment: For more details, look up [the Etymological Fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the impression from [this footnote #6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypostatic_union#cite_note-6) ...

> here are only five occurrences in the NT, in gereral used in the sense of assurance, substance, reality. Definition (lit: an underlying): (a) confidence, assurance, (b) a giving substance (or reality) to, or a guaranteeing, (c) substance, reality. The occurrences are: 2 Corinthians 9:4 – ἐν τῇ **ὑποστάσει** ταύτῃ (by this confidence); 2 Corinthians 11:17 – ταύτῃ τῇ **ὑποστάσει** τῆς καυχήσεως (in this confidence of boasting); Hebrews 1:3 –χαρακτὴρ τῆς **ὑποστάσεως** αὐτοῦ φέρων (and the exact representation of His nature, and upholds); Hebrews 3:14 –ἀρχὴν τῆς **ὑποστάσεως** μέχρι τέλους (the beginning of our assurance firm); and Hebrews 11:1 – πίστις ἐλπιζομένων **ὑπόστασις** πραγμάτων ἔλεγχος (faith is the assurance of [things] hoped). See: http://biblehub.com/str/greek/5287.htm

... that the derivation from the roots is: "stand under", hence "substance" and "underlying", also "support", also "confidence" (as in, "a belief is substantiated or justified by some reason").

In that context, hypostasis is viewed as a good (desirable, or at least reasonable or sensible) thing.

I think that should be contrasted with (not confused with) one of the modern usages of [reification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(fallacy)), where that's viewed as (or used to denote) a type of logical fallacy.

So its meaning can be a bit broad: ranging from (logical) substantiation to (illogical) reification.

Comment: I think readers of this answer should also be aware of [the warning I left under the question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/450115/what-does-hypostatize-mean#comment1083399_450115) which was asked by the same user.

Comment: My Dad was a classicist, told me Latin and Greek roots of English and French words. Obviously people can and do use words without having that information, but IMO it helps one to "understand" a word. In this case (hypostasis) I was puzzled, because it almost seems to have two opposite meanings. Also hypo/hyper is usually simple enough to understand in a word, and meaningful -- I wanted to know what it's doing in this word.

Comment: The fact that the meaning and the etymology seemed like opposite meanings, and puzzled you, is the very heart of the Etymological Fallacy. Instead of helping you “understand” the word, as you say, it did the complete opposite. You had read the dictionary definitions and *already knew* what the word meant. It was only on seeking a connection to etymology that you lost hold  of that understanding. That’s the problem. The Etymological Fallacy is just another example of what are called “genetic fallacies”, improper reasoning from “origins”, an eternal cognitive bias that has much trouble.

Comment: This looks like it should have been included in the question as part of what's confusing you, not written up separately as an answer.

Comment: @DanBron The etymological "fallacy" is the assumption that the etymology *defines* the meaning, that the antique meaning is more true than the modern meaning. I want to be informed by a knowledge of the etymology. FWIW that's because it's used occasionally in the translation of a Pali or Sanskrit word (i.e. *papañca* or *prāpaṇtya*) so I wanted to survey the several meanings/usages of this word.

Comment: @1006a No this is an answer -- I don't need another answer (though you're welcome to add another or to correct this one).  People posted pseudo-answers as comments under the question, which pointed me to further references (e.g. the "Hypostatic union" article), which told me what I wanted. I could have left the question unanswered at that point, but decided to answer it (by posting an answer).

Comment: @ChrisW No, the EM isn’t that the older meaning supersedes the newer ones, but that the newer meaning has some obligation to the older meaning or the constituent morphemes, that must align to them and not oppose them. That’s simply not the case for example, “homophobe” was a novel coinage (so it had no “older meaning”), and it means “bias against homosexuals”, but people who fall into the EM cavil that it should mean “fear” of homosexuals (it doesn’t; and taking this further it “should” mean “fear of sameness”).

Comment: But even by your more restrictive definition of the EM, your Q falls squarely into it. Look at your title “What does X mean?”. Look at your first para “I read several dictionary definitions of X, and I understand what they say”. Ok, so what’s the... ah, read he third para “In particular, how does this *meaning* relate to or derive from its *etymology*”. There’s the rub. You’re there. You have a question of about *meaning*, but because you couldn’t square it with the *etymology*, you thought you didn’t understand he word. That’s it. That’s what lying at the bottom of the EM our feels like.

Comment: @DanBron I thought I was paraphrasing the  [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy) which you referenced in another comment. Yes I guess "homophobe" is analogous to "xenophobe", which IMO implies "aversion" or "dislike".  Also [associated with war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phobos_(mythology)) for what it's worth.